# How to hide div when specific menu item is clicked - Angular 6 +

Tags: angular

How can I show a div when an item is clicked in angular?

Div show fine when I click list item, but dsn't disappear when I navigate to other menu items.

**html**

```
<li>
  <a class="nav-link slots" (click)="showme = true" >Slots</a>
</li>
<div ng-hide="showme">
  <div class="ribbon" *ngIf="game.categories[0]">
    <span>TOP</span>
  </div>

  <div class="ribbon" *ngIf="game.categories[2]">
    <span>NEW</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
showme: boolean = false;
```

Comment: You will need to set showme back to false when navigating away. Please provide more details. Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to provide a solid question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite able to understand the problem here. ng-hide is angularjs method of showiing things. Try ngIf?

For reference: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `<button (click)>` instead of an `<a (click)>`.

Can you provide a stackblitz to demonstrate the problem?

And as Kishin says,

```
<div *ngIf="showMe">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

taking for granted that

`showme : boolean = false;`

is declared in a .ts file,

it is a known issue, using **ngIf instead of ng-hide** it will works, also using

```
[ngClass]="{'ng-hide': expression}"
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it right by adding showme = false to other list items
Thanks.